# Jquery script only works after switching IE windows

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

The script below queries a php service that returns a JSON response. Buttons are created for each returned record, allowing the user to delete that record from the database. A link is also created below to refresh the data.

This all works fine in IE, Chrome, Safari...IE (tried 8 & 9), however, is having a strange issue.

When the page loads, I am able to refresh the data by clicking the 'refresh' link. After this, clicking has no effect UNLESS I open the same page in a different IE window, click the link in the new window, and return to the original window. The 'refresh' link then works on the new window ONE time. It then turns into a vicous cycle.

Your help is appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getNew(){ 
$('#new').remove();
$.getJSON('service.php', function(data) {

  var items = [];

  items.push('<tr><th>EmplId</th><th>ExternalID</th><th>Name</th></tr>');   

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {

    var indiv = val.toString().split(",");
    items.push('<tr>');
    var id = indiv[0];

    $.each(indiv, function(index, value) {
        items.push('<td align="center" id="' + index + '">' + value + '</td>');
    });

    items.push('<td  class="updateButton" align="center" onclick=\'return update("'+id+'")\'>Update</td>');

  });
    items.push('<tr><td  class="refreshButton" align="center" onclick=\'return getNew();\'>Refresh </td></tr>');

  $('<table/>', {
    'id': 'new',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
}



function update (emplID){
$.ajax({
  url: "service.php?emplID="+emplID,
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){

 $('#new').remove();

 getNew();

  }
});
}

</script>

</head>
```

I have disabled the cache still to no avail. The ONLY way to make the link work is to open the same page in a separate window, click the link, and return to the original window. Is there any solution to this?

```
$(".refreshButton").live( "click" , function() { getNewStudents(); 
$.ajax({
  url: "studentService.php?emplID=",
  cache: false,
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){

 $('#newStudents').remove();

 getNewStudents();

  }
});
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to go jQuery all the way. Instead of writing an `onclick` to each link, add a subscriber to your JavaScript file:

`$(".refreshButton").live( "click" , function() { getNew(); } );`

`live()` will attach the onclick handler to all existing and future elements that match the selector.

HTH.

**EDIT:**

BTW, here's the API documentation for `live()`, if you're interested: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: There seems to be a general consensus that using delegate() is better than live():  http://test.kingdesk.com/jquery/bind_live_delegate.php

Comment: I have tried using .live and I get the same results. Is this explainable?
    $(".refreshButton").live( "click" , function() {    getNewStudents(); 
    $.ajax({
    url: "studentService.php?emplID=",
    context: document.body,
     success: function(){
 
     $('#new').remove();
 
     getNew();
 
      }
    });
    } );

Comment: Um, I'd have to say it looks about right, although you would get better formatting by amending your original post. As @Steve Wellens mentions below, you might be running into a cache problem. Trying adding `cache: false` to your `$.ajax` call. You also might find it simpler to use `$.get` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe IE is caching the page more thoroughly.
Also, have you tried using compatibility view?

Comment: Yes, I have tried compatibility view and inPrivate, same results. This script works fine in FF, Chrome, and Safari